# Access robots on geoip htaccess

Tags: geoip

I blocked my target countries using below code in htaccess. But by blocking America, the access of Google bots and... will be blocked. I don't want Google access to be cut off. please guide me

```
GeoIPEnable On
# Chosen country by country code
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US Country
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE TR Country
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CN Country
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CA Country
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RU Country

<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env Country
</RequireAll>
```